# Check text size in byte

Tags: php

I have string

```
$text = "this is my text";
```

and i want to know the size(byte), not text length.

so i tried to use

> filesize();

but i get Error

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for this is my text

and if i tried to use

> mb_strlen()

it only count the text lenght, not the size.

How to know the text size ? i want the result something like "1024 bytes"

Thanks

Comment: `strlen` is all you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your case byte length is the same as string length. use `strlen` like so:

```
$length = strlen($text);
```

or if you want to be complicated use:

```
file_put_contents('myfile.txt', $text);
$length = filesize('myfile.txt');
unlink('myfile.txt');
```

Comment: I want to get the size in byte, not the length. something like "1024 bytes"

Comment: Owh i c, i tried to save the same text in .txt file, and tried to use filesize();. It show me the same result. Thanks Omar

Comment: @Ahmad You may also delete the file after that :)